# Which programming language is this?

Tags: printing

It was used in a .lbl file that was being sent to one of our toshiba folders.

I was told it was a toshiba printer specific language, but i'm having trouble finding any manuals or anything for it online.

```
{D0243,0483,0223|}
{C|}
{PV00;0431,0089,0072,0077,B,22,B=*locn_brcd|}
{XS;I,0001,0002C5011|}
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: it seems like prn file used from printers

Answer (score 2):

most likely it is TCPL (Tec Printer Command Language) - not so much a programming language, more a markup language used by toshiba printer driver to tell the printer what element goes where, how much line feed to use etc.

We had to build some of those commands from scratch to feed barcode printer in a small project that couldn't afford a full higher level SDK.

It was...not entirely pleasant to work with, as we couldn't get much documentation at that time